# Isn't positron capture theoretically possible?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, antimatter, radioactivity

I've heard of $\beta^-$ decay,

$$n \rightarrow p^+ + e^- + \bar \nu_e$$

$\beta^+$ decay,

$$p^+ \rightarrow n + e^+ + \nu_e$$

and electron capture,

$$p^+ + e^- \rightarrow n + \nu_e$$

but every time I've googled "positron capture," which I assume would probably happen as

$$n + e^+ \rightarrow p^+ + \bar \nu_e$$

I've never found any reliable results that mention anything about it other than a footnote on some website that mentions that a positron would annihilate with an electron in the cloud surrounding a nucleus before it even came close to the nucleus. However, if all of the electrons surrounding the nucleus were removed, then I see no reason why this reaction would not be possible at least in theory.

Is positron capture *theoretically* possible? If not, why not? If so, what nuclei could allow for this process to occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Positron capture is not possible, and here is why: The "capture" part refers to the fact that the electron is taken from its atomic orbit around the nucleus containing the proton with which it reacts. Since a positron cannot for a bound state with a nucleus--it can't be captured.

Nevertheless, $e^+p(n, \bar{\nu}_e)$, is a perfectly good scattering reaction.

Comment: of course if we just stick to "positron capture" one could imagine in an anti atom ( with antiprotons and antineutron and postitrons around) capturing the positron and turning  into an antineutron. They have only managed to create antihydrogen, home.cern/about/engineering/storing-antimatter

Comment: One could direct a positron beam onto a neutron beam to force the situation. The cross-section would then by typical of low-energy weak interaction (i.e. terrible), but it ought to be possible to observe the reaction the OP proposes (counting missing momentum as exposing the neutrino). A heck of a lot of time, energy, and money for little obvious gain.

Comment: @dmckee You may know this already, but helium-3 makes a good neutron stand in (it's stable, polarizable), and DESY has a positron beam (for storage lifetime vs. electrons), and that experiment was done: http://www-hermes.desy.de.

Answer (score 0):

"Positron capture" does not normally happen. However if temperatures are high and pressures are high(like in the sun) it is possible for positron capture to occur. This could be a way that occasionally neutrons turn into protons.