Can neutron decay be accelerated?
Is there any way (by external factors) that can speed up the decay of a neutron?
Some other discussion on it : reddit

See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/375884/isnt-positron-capture-theoretically-possible

Yes.
Put it in a nucleus near the neutron drip line, or stick it in a $^7$Li for:
$$ ^8{\rm Li} \rightarrow ^8{\rm Be} + e^- + \bar\nu_e $$
with a half-life of 0.84 seconds.
The other choice is place it in a core collapse supernova within 11 minutes of collapse?
Basically you can change the amplitude or the phase space. See http://aesop.phys.utk.edu/ph611/2012/projects/Hayes.pdf for details.

Thanks for letting me know!
